# Managing schemes in a way, for each scheme there should be different AppIcon, Splash Screen, Language,Localized Strings and App Name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on Iphone Application, now little modifications. Client want two/three clones of same App.

what I want is, for each selected scheme there should be different

- App Icon
- App Name
- Localized strings
- Splash Screen
- Language

and obviously different plists.

any question from Question and suggestion/solution will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

First approach: go with different targets. Simply assign the appropriate assets to separate targets and compile and upload separately.

Second approach: use git branches (that is my preferred method). Git is built into Xcode and is a versioning system that lets you specify several different parallel versions of the same app. Again, switch branch compile and upload. I am managing a few dozen "white label" apps in this way.

Comment: First Approach: I gone through this approach, that's why i posted question, i don't know how to link separate plist to each scheme. Always it connects to default info.plist no matters which scheme and with which settings is selected


Second Approach: Truthfully speaking I don't know how to do this, please explain, if you have some tutorial URL or sample project

Thanks

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. [Here](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/git/) is one. The one I used is [Pro Git](http://progit.org/).